# Does it make sense to store resources from the API in Vuex

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, vuex

I`m new with Vue and I develop API with Laravel. Client of API is Vue application. My API has several resources that cannot be changed from the frontend (Categories, Products etc), they can only be retrieved from API. So does it make sense to store this resources in Vuex storage or it's better to just get them directly where I need them without using Vuex?

Comment: Categories and products, do they change often?

Comment: It makes sense if you use the data in multiple, different, unrelated components. If you use the data in only a single component, or a cluster of tightly coupled components, it's much easier to understand to just load the data once in the highest common parent. This is of course just my preference, as this is a purely subjective question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. Ok, let's pretend this is an online store. I get a page by page list of products (for example, 10 per page). How best to organize viewing a specific product and adding products to the cart from the Vue`s (Vuex) point of view?